# Redirect from login

Tags: ios

Guys would really appreciate it if someone here could help me quickly, I am having a problem where i need to login to my app and then be automatically redirected to the next page, thats really all it is.

thank you in advance

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    credentialsDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray     arrayWithObjects:@"password", @"1234", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"username",@"amit", nil]];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [_webview1 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://nutriments.info/test1/test3.php"]]];
}
- (IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
- (IBAction)dismiss1:(id)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
- (IBAction)dismiss2:(id)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
- (IBAction)dismiss3:(id)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
- (IBAction)dismiss4:(id)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)enterCredentials {
    if ([[credentialsDictionary objectForKey:usernameField.text]isEqualToString:passwordField.text]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Correct Password" message:@"This   password is correct." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil]
        [alert show];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Incorrect Password" message:@"This     password is incorrect." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)sendtoadmin:(id)sender {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailContoller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    [mailContoller setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    NSString *email = @"******@hotmail.com";
    NSArray *emailArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:email, nil];
    NSString *message = [@[_textview.text, _textview1.text,     _textview2.text]componentsJoinedByString: @"\n"];
    [mailContoller setMessageBody:message isHTML:NO];
    [mailContoller setToRecipients:emailArray];
    [mailContoller setSubject:@"Query"];
    [self presentViewController:mailContoller animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)touchesBegan4:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [[self textview] resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

Comment: I don't understand where you want to be redirected?

Comment: For this, you would need a callback from your login service / API. I see none in your code.

Comment: Why do you have 5 IBActions that do the same thing?...

Comment: well the password and username is coded inside it all i need to do is know how i can redirect the page after clicking login, so if it is successful it will go to the next page otherwise it won't.

Comment: you can use your login as a modal and dismiss it on successful login.

Comment: @southpark that sounds like what i need could you just show me how i would dismiss it on a successful  login?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pushViewController:animated:completion:` on `self.navigationController` to push a view.
If you use this method in the 'success' part of your `enterCredentials` function, you can automatically redirect the view. E.G.:

```
- (IBAction)enterCredentials {
    if ([[credentialsDictionary objectForKey:usernameField.text]isEqualToString:passwordField.text])
    {
        InsertNextViewControllerClassHere *nextViewController = [[InsertNextViewControllerClassHere alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES completion: nil];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Incorrect Password" message:@"This     password is incorrect." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

You might want to save a variable `is_logged_in` in your NSUserDefaults, too.
This is done by the following code:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"is_logged_in"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

Then, create a new method `- viewWillAppear` which will check the boolean you just set using:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([userDefaults boolForKey:@"is_logged_in"])
{
    InsertNextViewControllerClassHere *nextViewController = [[InsertNextViewControllerClassHere alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES completion: nil];
}
```

---

*Please note that it is unsafe to have all the passwords saved on the device itself. (Unencrypted, it seems)
You might want to move this part to the server, encrypting the password before you send it.*

Comment: thank you i will try this and i will be sure to accept your answer once i check.

Comment: hi sorry so sound very dumb but isn't there an easier way to just allow it to go to the next page?

Comment: Just use the two lines that push the view controller (InsertNextViewControllerClassHere *nextViewController) and (self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController).

Comment: i just get errors after connecting the enter credentials button to the next page

Answer (score 0):

To present your login view use

```
UIViewController myLoginViewController = [[MyLoginViewController alloc] initwithNibNamed:"MyLoginViewController"]; 
[myTabViewController presentModalViewController:myLoginViewController animated:YES];
```

to Hide it use

```
//This should be done from the original View Controller i.e. myTabViewController preferably in a delegate called by the modal view controller.
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```